# Live click except child?

Tags: jquery

I have the following div:

```
<div class="main">
     <button class="quick">sample</button>
</div>
```

And i have this script:

```
    $('.main').live('click', function() {
```

However, id like to modify it so if the button within the `main` is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: `live`: deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".main .quick").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent.

You should also use `.on` instead of `.live` (if it's available; otherwise use `.delegate`).

Just in case you actually need event delegation, you would do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".main .quick", function (e) {
```

Comment: But if i do that, the click doesnt fire when `.main` is clicked. I still want to be able to fire a click event on `.main`, just not when the `.quick` within is clicked

Comment: @JonahKatz you have profoundly misunderstood my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4ubQn/1/